# Customize Facebook invite dialog box

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can generate the invite dialog box via:

```
   FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests', 
      message: 'Here is a new Requests dialog...'});
```

My question is 2 folds:

1. How do I change the look and feel of that box (without having to
   use FBML since it's being deprecated).
2. How do I determine how many invites were sent?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No way
2. Return data (request_ids) - all sent requests
   http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Comment: per #1.  Is there no workaround? or a way to build your own dialog box  + graph api to mimic the invite feature?

Comment: Yes, you can. You need to login user, get his friends and draw your own dialog box. But your invites can only posts to user's friends walls. Original Request Dialog send only notifications to users.

Comment: @AntonMelnikov: #1 MafiaWars 2 has nice list of my friends with edited design. Couldn't I just get the list, let the user select and then just send more than one request to `FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
          message: 'My Great Request',
          to: user_id_selected, 
        }, requestCallback);` ?